# sass/scss #{$value + s} in less

Tags: css, sass, less

there is a variable @value: 5;
and I want to put it in transition-delay.
(Transition-delay: @value;)

but transition-delay property can contain only seconds

**How the @value can be turned into seconds**

I read less documentation but I haven't found any information about this problem
(maybe I am inattentive)

```
.delay-for-every-child (@i) when (@i > 0) {
    &:nth-child(@{i}) {
        @value: (@i / 10 + 0.2);
        transition-delay: @value; // here is this value
    }

    .delay-for-every-child(@i - 1);
}
```

please, help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `s` to the `0.2`:

```
@iterations: 5;
.delay-for-every-child (@i) when (@i > 0) {
    &:nth-child(@{i}) {
        @value: (@i / 10 + 0.2s);
        transition-delay: @value; // here is this value
    }

    .delay-for-every-child(@i - 1);
}

.delay-for-every-child(@iterations);
```

Compiles to:

```
:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```